# Structs in events

Tags: solidity, events, struct

Is it possible to emit structs in Events nowadays? Like"

```js
contract MyContract {
   struct MyStruct {
      uint a;
      uint b;
   }

   event MyEvent(MyStruct indexed my);
}
```